# MikTex Directories Question

Tags: miktex

PlainTex user here... Long time PCTex user wishing to migrate to MikTex. I like PCTex, but, it seems that the company has faded away over time, as there has not been a significant update in many years. Still works for me, but I am afraid I am on borrowed time.

Using TexWorks, pdfTeX

I have a collection of various makro files created over a period of decades that i use regularly.

I am trying to configure MikTex to have that directory in the PATH so that, upon typing \input makro in a generic plain tex file, it will find that directory and retrieve the makros in that file, located in a directory taught to MikTex.

I am failing to get MikTeX to be able to find that directory.

I have added the path to Settings-->Directories, under tasks i have refreshed the file name database, and... I get an error upon typesetting saying "cant find file makro.tex".

IF I copy the makro file to the directory of the source file, works fine.

Where am i going off the rails, or what, fundamentally, am I not understanding.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you install your macros file  respecting the t.d.s. structure? If they are plain TeX macros, it should be installed in `local_directory\tex\generic`.

Comment: ok, this gets me a bit further. I am still trying to understand TDS. I will try this now. THANK YOU for replying.

Comment: Got it working. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.